# Drag over effect using XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, drag-and-drop

I am trying to change `Background` of a `Border` when user is dragging a file on it.

[image: r]

I want to define the effect using `XAML` only.

I tried the below but the `Background` is not changed when dragging a file on the `Border`.

```
<Border Name="dropBorder" BorderThickness="1" AllowDrop="True">    
     <Border.Triggers>
         <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="DragOver">
               <BeginStoryboard>      
                     <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                            <ColorAnimation From="Transparent" To="#FF444444" Duration="0:0:0.5" />
                      </Storyboard>
               </BeginStoryboard>
          </EventTrigger>
      </Border.Triggers>
      <TextBlock Text="Drag and drop file(s) here"  Foreground="Gray" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="10"/>
 </Border>
```

I also tried to use `DragEnter` as below with no results

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Border.DragEnter">
      <BeginStoryboard>
           <Storyboard>
                <ColorAnimation  Storyboard.TargetName="dropBorder"
                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background"
                                 Duration="0:0:0.5" 
                                 From="Transparent" To="#FF444444"/>
           </Storyboard>
       </BeginStoryboard>
</EventTrigger>
```

Answer (score 2):

I didnt quite meet your 100% requirement.  I created an attached property, which I set via code-behind, so you will want to assess this.  Also, moved the color animation around as you were trying to animate a brush, not a color.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:wpfApplication1="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SharedBackgroundBrush" Color="Transparent" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Border Name="dropBorder" BorderThickness="1" AllowDrop="True" DragEnter="DropBorder_OnDragEnter" DragLeave="DropBorder_OnPreviewDragLeave" Background="{StaticResource SharedBackgroundBrush}">
        <Border.Style>
            <Style>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="wpfApplication1:DragDropHelper.IsDragOver" Value="True">
                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard Storyboard.Target="{StaticResource SharedBackgroundBrush}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color">
                                    <ColorAnimation From="Transparent" To="Yellow" Duration="0:0:0.5" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <Trigger.ExitActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard Storyboard.Target="{StaticResource SharedBackgroundBrush}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color">
                                    <ColorAnimation From="Yellow" To="Transparent" Duration="0:0:0.5" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </Trigger.ExitActions>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Border.Style>
        <TextBlock Text="Drag and drop file(s) here"  Foreground="Gray" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="10"/>
    </Border>
</Window>
```

Code:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void DropBorder_OnDragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {            
            DragDropHelper.SetIsDragOver((DependencyObject)sender, true);         
        }

        private void DropBorder_OnPreviewDragLeave(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            DragDropHelper.SetIsDragOver((DependencyObject)sender, false);         
        }
    }

    public class DragDropHelper
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsDragOverProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "IsDragOver", typeof (bool), typeof (DragDropHelper), new PropertyMetadata(default(bool)));

        public static void SetIsDragOver(DependencyObject element, bool value)
        {
            element.SetValue(IsDragOverProperty, value);
        }

        public static bool GetIsDragOver(DependencyObject element)
        {
            return (bool) element.GetValue(IsDragOverProperty);
        }
    }
}
```